# How to obtain Health data from the last 7 days

Tags: ios, swift, date, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I'm trying to obtain the steps from the last 7 days, but I could not find how to do it. *What i would like to receive is an array of 7 elements in which every element is a Day with it respectives total steps*. I currently have this code, which obtains today's steps:

```
//Gets the steps
func getTodaysSteps(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!

    let now = Date()
    let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)

    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { (_, result, error) in
        guard let result = result, let sum = result.sumQuantity() else {
            print("Failed to fetch steps = \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "N/A")")
            completion(0.0)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()))
        }
    }
    healthKitStore.execute(query)
}
```

And I call the function like this:

```
getTodaysSteps { (steps) in
        self.stepsNumber = Int(steps)
    }
```

Comment: An easier way to do this is to execute a single HKStatisticsCollectionQuery (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery`, which will do the date math for you and bucket the results automatically. Here's an example that should provide the step counts for the last 7 days:

```
    let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!

    let now = Date()
    let exactlySevenDaysAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: -7), to: now)!
    let startOfSevenDaysAgo = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: exactlySevenDaysAgo)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfSevenDaysAgo, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)

    let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery.init(quantityType: stepsQuantityType,
                                                 quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
                                                 options: .cumulativeSum,
                                                 anchorDate: startOfSevenDaysAgo,
                                                 intervalComponents: DateComponents(day: 1))

    query.initialResultsHandler = { query, results, error in
        guard let statsCollection = results else {
            // Perform proper error handling here...
        }

        statsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: startOfSevenDaysAgo, to: now) { statistics, stop in

            if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
                let stepValue = quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am always getting 0 and in health app step count is not zero. can u help?

Answer (score 3):

There's even more simpler solution here.

```
func getTotalSteps(forPast days: Int, completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    // Getting quantityType as stepCount
    guard let stepsQuantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount) else {
        print("*** Unable to create a step count type ***")
        return
    }

    let now = Date()
    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: -days), to: now)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)

    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { _, result, _ in
        guard let result = result, let sum = result.sumQuantity() else {
            completion(0.0)
            return
        }
        completion(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()))
    }
    execute(query)
}
```

Now to call just use the following code:

```
HKHealthStore().getTotalSteps(forPast: 30) { totalSteps in
    print(totalSteps)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only change you have to implement is to change the `Date` object you supply as the `startWith` parameter to your `HKStatisticsQuery`. You can create a `Date` object representing the start of the day 7 days ago by first going back exactly 7 days in time using `Calendar.date(byAdding:,to:)`, then calling `startOfDay(for:)` on that object.

```
let now = Date()
let exactlySevenDaysAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: -7), to: now)!
let startOfSevenDaysAgo = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: exactlySevenDaysAgo)
let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfSevenDaysAgo, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)
```

Comment: Thank you! unfortunately I expressed myself badly. What i would like to receive is an array of 7 elements in which every element is a Day with it respectives total steps. already edited the post